# Django-pgcrypto EncryptedCharField with Choices breaks the Selectbox in Django Admin View

Tags: python, django, django-models, drop-down-menu, django-admin

The EncryptedCharField of Django-pgcrypto breaks the Selectbox in Django Admin View. How can I fix it?

Before:

```
class Person(Model):

work_hours_mon = models.DecimalField('Montag',
    default = 8,
    validators=[
        MaxValueValidator(24),
        MinValueValidator(0)
    ]
)
```

[image]

After:

```
class Person(Model):

work_hours_mon = pgcrypto.EncryptedDecimalField('Montag',
    default = 8,
    validators=[
        MaxValueValidator(24),
        MinValueValidator(0)
    ],
    key = settings.KEY_FOR_DJANGO_PGCRYPTO,
)
```

[image]

This is the Traceback:

```
[15/Jan/2019 14:01:44] "GET /admin/jsi18n/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3189
[15/Jan/2019 14:01:44] "GET /static/admin/img/icon-changelink.svg HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[15/Jan/2019 14:01:44] "GET /static/admin/img/icon-addlink.svg HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[15/Jan/2019 14:01:44] "GET /static/admin/fonts/Roboto-Regular-webfont.woff HTTP/1.1" 200 80304
[15/Jan/2019 14:01:44] "GET /static/admin/fonts/Roboto-Light-webfont.woff HTTP/1.1" 200 81348
[15/Jan/2019 14:01:44] "GET /static/admin/fonts/Roboto-Bold-webfont.woff HTTP/1.1" 200 82564
Not Found: /favicon.ico
[15/Jan/2019 14:01:44] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 14604
[15/Jan/2019 14:01:44] "GET /static/admin/img/icon-calendar.svg HTTP/1.1" 200 1086
```

Thanks.

Comment: can you add the traceback?

Comment: Traceback added.

Comment: That's not a traceback, that's only the URLs called. Does your terminal show which error is thrown? because it should. Without a proper traceback there's no way to see what's going wrong.